# Using XSL to pass an XML attribute as an id into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

Hope you can help point me in the right direction with this problem...

What I am trying to do:
I have an XML file that I'm turning into HTML using XSLT.  Part of that includes adding a "hide" button.  I want to use the hide button to remove the node from the XML, and my idea is to give the button the same id as the myId attribute in the relevant XML element, which makes it easy to match the onClick of the button with the XML element to hide.

Here's a bit of the XML:

```
<sectionStatement myId="1">Awesome statement</sectionStatement>
<sectionStatement myId="2">I am a statement</sectionStatement>
<sectionStatement myId="3">I am another statement</sectionStatement>
```

Here's a bit of the XSL where I' stuck:

```
<xsl:for-each select="sectionStatement">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/><a class='showHideBtn' href='#'>Hide</a></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

...so I want to end up with 3 paras of html, each with a "Hide" button, and I want the button to have the relevant id (1,2 or 3).  It is the equivalent of adding `id="<xsl:value-of select='@myId'/>"` into the  tag ...but I've tried that and it doesn't work!

Thanks for your advice :-)
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute value template `<a id="{@myId}" class="showHideBtn" href="#">Hide</a>`.

Comment: Neat and tidy and does the job perfectly for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xsl:attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_attribute.asp) to add dynamic, conditional attributes and apply templates  to elements.

```
<p>
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
    optionalText<xsl:value-of select="@myId"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</p>
```

If you already know the value, the transformation syntax is simpler.

```
<xsl:for-each select="sectionStatement">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <a class='showHideBtn' href='#' id='{@myId}'>
    Hide
    </a>
  </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```